# Algebra: groups

Tags: group-theory

Let m and n be two positive integers with gcd(m, n) = 1. Prove that Z/mZ × Z/nZ is congruent to Z/mnZ. [Consider φ : Z → Z/mZ × Z/nZ given by φ (a) = (a mod m, a mod n).]

My Solution:

Consider φ : Z → Z/mZ × Z/nZ given by φ (a) = (a mod m, a mod n). We see that this is a homomorphism. Let (x, y) ∈ Z/mZ × Z/nZ where (x mod m, y mod n) ∈ Z/mZ × Z/nZ. Since gcd(m, n) = 1 there exists s,t ∈ Z such that ms + nt = 1. If we multiply both sides by x − y we get

ms + nt = 1

(x − y)(ms + nt) = 1(x − y)

xms + xnt − yms − ynt = x − y

y + xnt − ynt = x − xms + yms

y + (x − y)nt = x + (y − s)ms

Let a = y + (x − y)nt = x + (y − x)ms then φ (a) = (x mod m, y mod n) so φ is surjective. We see that mnZ ⊂ kerφ . If x ∈ kerφ then x mod m = 0 mod m and x mod n = 0 mod n so m|x and n|x. Then mn|x and so x ∈ mnZ. By the first isomorphism theorem, Z/mZ × Z/nZ ∼= Z/mnZ.

(Checking my work, Z are integers)

Comment: You mean isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $\varphi$ is surjective seems correct, because it's the classical proof that any system of congruences
$$
\begin{cases}
z\equiv x\pmod{m}\\
z\equiv y\pmod{n}
\end{cases}
$$
(in the unknown $z$) has a solution. Now that you have proved that the map is surjective, you know by cardinality reasons that $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\Z/\ker\varphi$ has order $mn$, but there is just one subgroup $H$ of $\Z$ such that $|\Z/H|=mn$, namely $H=mn\Z$.

Answer (score -1):

You should end up getting $y+(x-y)nt=x+(y-$**x**)$ms$ not $y+(x-y)nt=x+(y-$**s**$)ms$.